# Iconos en Semantic-ui -tamaños que no cambian-

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, semantic-ui

Continúo dando mis primeros pasos en Semantic-ui y ahora estoy con cuatro simples botones sociales que los armo con iconos de semantic.
Para ello los defino asi:

```
<div>
    <i class="huge mini bordered facebook icon mi_boton_facebook"></i>
    <i class="huge small bordered google plus circle icon mi_boton_google"></i>
    <i class="huge large bordered teal twitter icon mi_boton_twitter"></i>
    <i class="huge massive bordered blue disabled linkedin icon mi_boton_linkedin"></i>
  </div>
```

[image: Y no existe variación de la imagen salvo usando la opción "massive"]

Lo extraño es que la documentación oficial dice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás dejando la clase `huge` en todos los íconos, por lo cual en 3 de los 4 casos la está utilizando en vez de `small`, `mini` y `large`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <i class="mini bordered facebook icon mi_boton_facebook"></i>
    <i class="small bordered google plus circle icon mi_boton_google"></i>
    <i class="large bordered teal twitter icon mi_boton_twitter"></i>
    <i class="massive bordered blue disabled linkedin icon mi_boton_linkedin"></i>
</div>
```

**¿Por qué?** En el código css de Semantic dichas clases están en el siguiente orden:

```
i.mini.icon,
i.mini.icons {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 0.4em;
}

i.tiny.icon,
i.tiny.icons {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

i.small.icon,
i.small.icons {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

i.icon,
i.icons {
  font-size: 1em;
}

i.large.icon,
i.large.icons {
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

i.big.icon,
i.big.icons {
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 2em;
}

i.huge.icon,
i.huge.icons {
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 4em;
}

i.massive.icon,
i.massive.icons {
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 8em;
}
```

En CSS, los valores de las propiedades que son aplicados finalmente son los de la última instancia que sea "leída".

Comment: un maestro Shaz !!! un verdadero maestro !!!